# Python Shutil module copytree

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I'm trying to use the shutil module in python. I want to copy a folder(`'movee'`) from my cwd to the `'D'` drive.
Here's the code:

```
import shutil

shutil.copytree('movee', 'D:\\')
```

But when i run it i get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'D:\\'
```

I tried running cmd as an administrator but the problem persisted.
Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Do you want to have a folder `D:\movee` afterwards, or do you want to copy the folders contents directly into `D:\ `?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, I want to have a folder 'D:\movee'

Answer (score 2):

The destination directory must not exist and is named in the destination argument for [`copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree).  (Other copy tools behave differently and use the basename of the source as the destination if the destination is a directory.)  This should work:

```
shutil.copytree('movee', 'D:\\movee')
```

The error is probably a consequence of an attempt to create the directory `D:\`.